# 400 Bad Request when sending a http request with Common Lisp usocket

Tags: http, lisp, httprequest, common-lisp, usocket

I'm using the following code to grab the url `http://brandonhsiao.com/essays.html`:

```
(defparameter *new-line* '(#\Return #\Newline))

(defun read-url (host port path)
  (let ((sock (usocket:socket-connect host port)))
    (format (usocket:socket-stream sock) "~A"
            (concatenate 'string
                         "GET " path " HTTP/1.1" *new-line*
                         "Connection: close" *new-line* *new-line*))
    (force-output (usocket:socket-stream sock))
    (do ((line
           (read-line (usocket:socket-stream sock) nil)
           (read-line (usocket:socket-stream sock) nil))
         (all ""))
      ((not line) all)
      (setf all (concatenate 'string all line *new-line*)))))

(print (read-url "brandonhsiao.com" 80 "/essays.html"))
```

This gives me a `400 Bad Request` error, but when I visit `http://brandonhsiao.com/essays.html` with Firefox, everything is fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure that new-line is sent to the socket as CRLF (HTTP requires newlines to be exactly CRLF). Since you use `format` to write text to socket's stream, newlines might be converted to LF.
You can use tcpdump or wireshark to see which bytes are sent to socket.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use the "drakma" package which is designed to do these kinds of things. It's available from Quicklisp.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to include the host.

```
(defparameter *new-line* '(#\Return #\Newline))

(defun read-url (host port path)
  (let ((sock (usocket:socket-connect host port)))
    (format (usocket:socket-stream sock) "~A"
            (concatenate 'string
                         "GET " path " HTTP/1.1" *new-line*
                         "Host: " host *new-line* *new-line*))
    (force-output (usocket:socket-stream sock))
    (do ((line
           (read-line (usocket:socket-stream sock) nil)
           (read-line (usocket:socket-stream sock) nil))
         (all ""))
      ((not line) all)
      (setf all (concatenate 'string all line " ")))))
```